# SQL Server: Updating a table row with first instance of multiple records from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. TableA & TableB. TableB already has rows of data but needs to be updated with information from TableA but the only matching information in each table does not identify a specific row, only a group of rows.  They look something like this:

```
TableA
StartTime                InstanceID  WorkCode  JobNumber  WorkCenter
=======================  ==========  ========  =========  ==========
2018-02-16 18:37:13.000  728282      103       725863     155
2018-02-17 00:54:12.000  728265      106       725863     155
2018-02-16 22:12:03.000  728110      103       725863     155

TableB
StartTime                InstanceID  WorkCode  JobNumber  WorkCenter
=======================  ==========  ========  =========  ==========
2018-02-16 18:39:53.000  NULL        NULL      725863     155
2018-02-17 00:52:18.000  NULL        NULL      725863     155
2018-02-16 22:08:26.000  NULL        NULL      725863     155
```

In the above example, these two tables were inserted approximately at the same time but not exact as you can see by their timestamps. The only truly matching information is JobNumber and WorkCenter. I need a way to match them up so I can do an UPDATE on TableB with the missing information from TableA.

The only way I think this can be done is to sort TableB by StartTime and do some sort of UPDATE via a loop where TableA will also have to be sorted by StartTime. Then, the first instance in TableA will match to the first instance in TableB and will be updated, then the second record/instance, the third, fourth, etc.

Any pros ever had to deal with this before where the only way to link them up is by their order?  Would creating temp tables help by creating a numbered column and linking that way?

Keep in mind, these tables have multitudes of different values in JobNumber and WorkCenter columns so I'll need to use WHERE clause filtering as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `row_number()`.  Fortunately, SQL Server allows subqueries (of this sort) in updates:

```
update b
    set instanceId = a.instanceId,
        workCode = a.workCode
from (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by jobNumber, WorkCenter order by starttime) as seqnum
      from tableb b
     ) b join
     (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by jobNumber, WorkCenter order by starttime) as seqnum
      from tablea a
     ) a
     on b.jobNumber = a.jobNumber and b.workCenter = a.workCenter and
        b.seqnum = a.seqnum;
```

I would validate after updating that everything really is in the right order.  It is a pain that the right information is not captured in `tableB` where you need it.  Depending on timing can lead to . . . shall I say, disappointment.

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this. It took me a while to get to this part of the project. I just constructed it and works perfectly for my needs.